# Efficiently retrieving data from MYSQL for batch processing?

Tags: mysql

I have a situation where I have data in a primary table with additional data in a bunch of associated tables. Given a list of IDs from the primary table, I need to retrieve all data for a batch process. This batch process is high volume so I need to implement it very efficiently.

I have implemented this using subqueries with `group_concat` and some mapping code, but I'm not very confident in it. It seems efficient but hard to maintain (particularly because my real implementation is much uglier, with it's many more tables and columns). Is this implementation a good idea? Is there some other `mysql` querying/joining approach I could take to improve this?

The structure of the data is similar to this, but in actuality I have many more tables and columns:

```
Objects
ID | column1 | column2 | column3
----------
1      a          b         c 
2      d          e         f


Attributes1
ID | ObjectsId| column1 | column2 | column3
--------------------
1         1       g        k           l
2         1       m        n           o
3         2       p        q           r
4         2       s        t           u


Attributes2
ID | ObjectsId| column1 | column2 | column3
--------------------
1         1         w        v         x
2         1         y        z         aa
3         2         bb       cc        dd
4         2         ee       ff        gg
```

This is approximately what the object produced by my application code should look like.

```
[
   {
   id = 1,
   column1 = a,
   Column2 = b,
   Column3 = c,
   Attributes1 = [
          {
          Id = 1, 
          ObjectsId = 1,
          Column1 = g,
          Column2 = k,
          Column3 = l
          },
          {
          Id = 2, 
          ObjectsId = 1,
          Column1 = m,
          Column2 = n,
          Column3 = o
          }]
     Attributes2 = [
         {
          Id = 1, 
          ObjectsId = 1,
          Column1 = w,
          Column2 = v,
          Column3 = x
          },
          {
          Id = 2, 
          ObjectsId = 1,
          Column1 = y,
          Column2 = z,
          Column3 = aa
         }]
   },
   {
   id = 2,
   column1 = d,
   Column2 = e,
   Column3 = f,
   Attributes1 = [
          {
          Id = 3, 
          ObjectsId = 2,
          Column1 = p,
          Column2 = q,
          Column3 = r
          },
          {
          Id = 4, 
          ObjectsId = 2,
          Column1 = s,
          Column2 = t,
          Column3 = u
          }]
     Attributes2 = [
         {
          Id = 3, 
          ObjectsId = 2,
          Column1 = bb,
          Column2 = cc,
          Column3 = dd
          },
          {
          Id = 4, 
          ObjectsId = 2,
          Column1 = ee,
          Column2 = ff,
          Column3 = gg
         }]
    }
]
```

This is my implementation:

```
private function get_all($object_ids)
{
    $a1 = " SELECT group_concat(a1.ID, '|', a1.ObjectsId, '|', a1.column1, '|', a1.column2, '|', a1.column3) 
              FROM   Attributes1 a1 
              WHERE  a1.objectsId = o.id";

    $a2 = " SELECT group_concat(a2.ID, '|', a2.ObjectsId, '|', a2.column1, '|', a2.column2, '|', a2.column3) 
              FROM   Attributes2 a2
              WHERE  a2.objectsId = o.id";

    $o = " SELECT ID, column1, column2, column3,
                     (%s) as attributes1_result,
                     (%s) as attributes2_result
              FROM   Objects o 
              WHERE  o.id IN (?)";

    $query   = sprintf($o, [$a1, $a2]);
    $results = $this->query($query, $object_ids);

    foreach ($results as &$result) {
        $a1Results = explode(',', $result['attributes1_result']);
        foreach ($a1Results as $a1Result) {
            $columns                = explode('|', $a1Result);
            $resultRow['id']        = $columns[0];
            $resultRow['ObjectsId'] = $columns[1];
            $resultRow['column1']   = $columns[2];
            $resultRow['column2']   = $columns[3];
            $resultRow['column3']   = $columns[4];

            $result['Attributes1'][] = $resultRow;
        }
        unset($result['attributes1_result']);

        $a2Results = explode(',', $result['attributes2_result']);
        foreach ($a2Results as $a2Result) {
            $columns                = explode('|', $a2Result);
            $resultRow['id']        = $columns[0];
            $resultRow['ObjectsId'] = $columns[1];
            $resultRow['column1']   = $columns[2];
            $resultRow['column2']   = $columns[3];
            $resultRow['column3']   = $columns[4];

            $result['Attributes2'][] = $resultRow;
        }
        unset($result['attributes2_result']);
    }

    return $results;
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind group_concat can have unexpected results as it limits to 1024

Comment: @RaymondNijland what does it limit to 1024?

Comment: i should have said GROUP_CONCAT defualts to a max of a string width of 1024 chars, after 1024 chars it truncates, but you can increase it..